# jQuery position not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a simple drag and drop game using HTML, CSS and jQuery. I have divs with silhouettes as backgrounds and around the middle there are the miniatures of the items you can drag and drop.

I want it so that when I drop a miniature in the right place, it moves to the center of the slot and scales up to cover the silhouette. Now it's only positioning correctly if I position it in the left top of the slot, every other way it's out of its place, even if I use center center.

Here is my CSS and HTML with the JavaScript:

http://jpst.it/AqX7

http://jpst.it/AqXa

```
ui.draggable.animate({
  "width": parentWidht
}, {
  duration: 200,
  queue: false
}).toggleClass("makeDraggable").position({
  of: $(this),
  my: "center center",
  at: "center center",
  collision: "none",
  using: function(css, calc) {
    $(this).animate(css, 200, "linear");
  }
}, {
  duration: 200,
  queue: false
});
```

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/yxuh0bad/1/)**

Why are my pictures not positioned in the center?

Thank you!

Comment: So if I'm using

`ui.draggable.animate({"width" : parentWidht}, { duration: 200, queue: false }).toggleClass("makeDraggable").position( { of: $(this), my: "center center", at: "center center", collision: "none", using: function(css, calc) {
        $(this).animate(css, 200, "linear");
    } },{ duration: 200, queue: false } );`


to animate, the picture is under the right side and left of the silhouettes. 


`.position( { of: $(this), my: "left top", at: "left top", collision: "none", using: function(css, calc)`


covers it, but I'd like it to work with center center.

Comment: Please provide enough information in your question, so everyone can understand your problem without visiting an external ressource.

Comment: Your CSS is invalid. What should `body { 0px; ... }` be?

Comment: try `parentWidth` instead of `parentWidht`

Comment: The typo with width was not relevant, I have been copy-pasting. The css is valid, that was a paste error. http://jpst.it/AqX7 here's the new version.